# Restrict others from viewing TFS shelveset

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, shelveset

Is there a way to restrict other users\my team members from viewing the shelvesets created by me?

Comment: What is the need behind this request, may I ask?

Comment: Suppose you did some code changes and shelved it for use at a later time. And the coding done was really a bad one. During appraisal if your lead\appraiser wants to take a look at your shelveset then you don't want him\her to find out that messy code. Also you don't want to totally lose that code by deleting the shelveset. Is there a way to hide a shelveset from a particular user?

Comment: I don't think someone will take the shelveset code's quality into account unless you check it in without required improvements into the code base (: As I noted in my answer, it is not possible as far as I know. It is common to store changes in shelvesets even if the code does not compile at all, it has many usage areas and one of them is to store the code and improve it in the future without keeping it in locally.

Comment: What you are saying does make sense. Anyways thanks much for all the help. Cheers :)

Comment: it looks like on TFS 2019 users can DELETE other users shelfsets - not good

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, there is no way to do this at the moment.

I tried to find some proof and found out this [msdn question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dfb91fe7-ca14-46e5-bb92-d3f7c63db429/private-shelvesets-team-foundation-server-2012?forum=tfsversioncontrol).